# Getting class not found error while running basic hibernate program

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Java Hibernate. I am writing a basic program but getting this error "Class not found pack1.Manager1"... Manager1 is my main class. Any help will be appreciated..

My files are like below:

1) hibernate/src/pack1/Employeeh.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="pack1">
    <class name="Employeeh" table="EMPLOYEEH">
        <id name="empid" column="EMP_ID" type="long">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="fname" column="FNAME">
        </property>
        <property name="email"/>
        </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

2) hibernate/src/pack1/Employeeh.java:

```
package pack1;
public class Employeeh
{
private int empid;
private String fname;
private String email;
public int getEmpid()
{
    return empid;
}
..
}
```

3) hibernate/src/pack1/Manager1.java:

```
package pack1;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
public class Manager1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Configuration c1=new Configuration();
    c1.configure();
    SessionFactory sf=c1.buildSessionFactory();
    Session s1=sf.openSession();
    Employeeh e1=new Employeeh();
    e1.setEmpid(1);
    e1.setFname("gourav");
    e1.setEmail("a@b.com");
}
}
```

4) hibernate/src/hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">gourav</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">baba</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
       <mapping resource="pack1/Employeeh.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you add full stack trace

Comment: I guess you need to compile your java files and make sure they are in the classpath at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project following what you posted (I have just used MySql instead of Oracle).
The result was successful for me ... No exceptions occurred!

I will just post you back all my files ...

The classes `Manager1` and `Employeeh` are exactly the same as yours in the `pack1` package.
My `hibernate.cfg.xml` is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
        <mapping resource="pack1/Employeeh.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And my `Employeeh.hbm.xml` is like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="pack1">
    <class name="Employeeh" table="EMPLOYEEH">
        <id name="empid" column="EMP_ID" type="long">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="fname" column="FNAME">
        </property>
        <property name="email" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

If everything is the same, my advice is to check that all the files are in the place that you specified in the configuration files and remember that you need a connector for using your db.

Hope this was helpful.